# Problem with TAdvMemo component (about wordwrap)

Tags: delphi, word-wrap, delphi-xe2, tms

I am using `TAdvMemo`. My problem is with the `WordWrap` property. It works very well when I type text in the text area, but when I add a string to it in code, it has no effect.

I have set `WordWrap` property to: `wwRightMargin` and `RightMargin` property to `80`, but not see other property that can help me, so i ask some idea as solve it?

i mean for example:

```
AdvMemo.Lines.Add(MyString);
```

where `MyString` is a string as: 'hello word'. When it is longer than 80 chars, and wrap is enabled, it should wrap to a new line, but instead it's all on the same line.

Comment: I can't understand. What does "print a string" mean?

Comment: Have you asked in the support forums of tmssoftware? You may get an answer there sooner.

Comment: Yes, but newsgroup not is much active :(

Comment: hello, @david, i mean for example:   AdvMemo.Lines.Add( MyString ) where MyString is a string as: 'hello word'.  When it is more long of 80 chars , and wrap is enabled, it should to go in a new line, but print all in same line.

Comment: @Marcello: Please edit your question to add the clarification you put in your comment to David, so that people can see it when they read the question itself.

Comment: @ken, ok i do, just i ask you an example, i am new here and yet not much practise, can so tell me better as to do, too for future? thanks again.

Comment: @Marcello: Log in with the same user account you used to post the question, and then go to the question. At the bottom left of your question, you'll see a link to "edit". Click that link. :)

Comment: @Marcello: Yes, it's fine. (I already did it for you, but you'll know for next time. :) )

Comment: well thanks, now i have understood better :) thanks again

Comment: @marcus, no, it add mystring to text line of advmemo. I have asked about as to do return back a string much long of was out margin right. In tms-newsgroup finally has answered me too, and told to add this instruction: AdvMemo.UpdateWrap. Tomorrow i check better. amd will know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AdvMemo.InsertText` instead. `Lines.Add` doesn't care about wrapping, it just handles some special chars in the string.

Answer (score 0):

After you added text to adv memo you must update wrap by calling UpdateWrap() function. Here is an example for you:

```
AdvMemo.Lines.Add(MyString);
AdvMemo.UpdateWrap();
```

or

```
AdvMemo.Lines.Text(MyString);
AdvMemo.UpdateWrap();
```

Be sure that WordWrap property of Adv Memo is different than wwNone.